# Hiding images and allowing text to appear Android

Tags: java, android

I am a newbie developer to android. I am trying to develop an application as a test run it is a Q and A app.

Can anyone help me with the following problem.

The pages have 2 radio buttons in a radio group, the center of the page has an image, and a few buttons(Next, Previous, Home) at the bottom. The part I need help with is when a user clicks on a radio button the image needs to disappear and the answer (Text) needs to appear. The app is Yes/No based so when either button is clicked the image need to disappear and text needs to replace it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code that you're trying to use?

Comment: You should read about the documentation in View on the android dev docs. If you can't understand the documentation, you won't get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the part i need help with is when a user clicks on a radio button the image needs to disappear and the answer (Text) needs to appear

To set an `OnClickListener`, so you know when a `View` has been clicked, you do...

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Some stuff
    }
});
```

Make sure you have setup your `Button` previously though, (by doing something like this):

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
```

Make sure you have setup your `TextView`s as well.

Now, to make a `View` disappear, you can use the `setVisibility(int)` method. Here's an example:

```
yourImage.setVisibility(View.GONE); // The image disappears
yourAnswer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // The answer text appears
```

You can add the above into the inner class of the `OnClickListener`, where I have put `// Some stuff`.